# Celery consuming whole memory

Tags: python, celery

I have a question concerning Celery.

Im sending a huge amount of data to the task queue.

I just tried it with so much task data that it doesn't fit into my memory.
The result is that celery gets killed because it uses the whole system memory.

Messages are not written to disk (broker rabbitmq) although

```
CELERY_DEFAULT_DELIVERY_MODE = 'persistent'
```

is set.

My task looks like this:

```
group(some_iterator).apply_async()
```

Does celery first try to serialize the whole data (I am using pickle) and then send it to the task queue?

If I run it the less data I can see that the tasks are written to disk.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you are sending huge amount of data to Celery task it could be better to store it in some database and send only to Celery task send just list of ids. When task is run make SQL query retrieving necessary data, processing and at the and saving results back to database.

Answer (score 0):

I found a possibility to achieve this behavior:

```
result_group = GroupResult(results = [])
for task_args task_arg_generator:
    task = analyze_task.delay(*task_args)
    result_group.add(task)


result_group.get()
# or :
result_group.join_native()
```

This serializes and sends each task alone and collects it in a ResultGroup which can be used to retrieve the group results.

But the solution I chose is store the data in a database and let the workers fetch it via id.

Hope that helps some people facing the same problem!